# casting a NSString to char problem

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i want to casting my NSString to a constant char 
the code is shown below :

```
NSString *date = @"12/9/2009";
char datechar = [date UTF8String]

NSLog(@"%@",datechar);
```

however it return the warning 
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
and cannot print the char properly,can somebody tell me what is the problem

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```
NSString* date = @"12/9/2009";
char* datechar = [date UTF8String];
NSLog(@"%s", datechar);
```

You need to use char* instead of char, and you have to print C strings using %s not %@ (%@ is for objective-c id types only).

Comment: UTF8String returns a const char*

Answer (score 8):

I think you want to use:

```
const char *datechar = [date UTF8String];
```

(note the * in there)

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 3):

Your code has 2 problems:

1) "char datechar..." is a single-character, which would only hold one char / byte, and wouldn't hold the whole array that you are producing from your date/string object. Therefore, your line should have a (*) in-front of the variable to store multi characters rather than just the one.

2) After the above fix, you would still get a warning about (char *) vs (const char *), therefore, you would need to "cast" since they are technically the same results. Change the line of:

`char datechar = [date UTF8String];`

into

`char *datechar = (char *)[date UTF8String];`

Notice (char *) after the = sign, tells the compiler that the expression would return a (char *) as opposed to it's default (const char *).

I know you have already marked the answer earlier however, I thought I could contribute to explain the issues and how to fix in more details.

I hope this helps.

Kind Regards
Heider

Answer (score 1):

I would add a * between char and datechar (and a %s instead of a %@):

```
NSString *date=@"12/9/2009"; char * datechar=[date UTF8String];
NSLog(@"%s",datechar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering for a long time to convert `NSString` to `char` to use for this function

```
-(void)gpSendDTMF:(char) digit callID: (int)cid;
```

I have tried every answer of this question/many things from Google search  but it did not work for me.

Finally I have got the solution.

---

**Solution:**

```
NSString *digit = @"5";

char dtmf;

char buf[2];

sprintf(buf, "%d", [digit integerValue]);

dtmf = buf[0];
```